# How to use Const Type Class in OOP C++?

Tags: c++, oop, constants

Could you explain why I cannot use the `const` type in a class?

Example code:

```
class Array {
    int *Arr;
    int n;
public:
    Array(int _n = 0) {
        Arr = new int[_n];
        n = _n;
    }
    ~Array(void) {
        delete []Arr;
    }
    friend void f(const Array &A) {
        A.Arr[0] = 3;  // why can the Arr[0], Arr[1] be changed the value ?
        A.Arr[1] = 4;
    //  A.n = 10;        // can not be changed because of 'const class type'
    }
};

void main()
{
    Array A(5);
    f(A);
}
```

When I call `f(A)`, I have defined the `const Array &A` in `f` but the elements in `void f()` are also changeable, but when I try with the code line `A.n = 10`, it is immutable.

Maybe I should define a `const` overloading operator or something in order to make all of the elements in `Arr` immutable.

**Question:** How can I make elements of `Arr` immutable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const Array &A` means that the `A` object is to be treated as constant, so its members can't be modified; but other objects, such as those in the array that `A.Arr` points to, are not.

`n = 10;` is impossible not because `A` is `const`, but because a friend function is not a member, so there is no `n`. The `const` would prevent `A.n = 10;`

You could prevent modification of the array by only allowing access via member functions, not via the pointer:

```
public:
    Type       & operator[](size_t i)       {return Arr[i];}
    Type const & operator[](size_t i) const {return Arr[i];}
```

Now `A[i]` can only be used for modification if `A` is mutable.

Comment: You said that all the members of the object are immutable using the const. But why the int *Arr is mutable ?. And can i force the pointer int *Arr be immutable ?

Comment: @Anderson: The pointer isn't mutable. The objects it points to are, since the `const` only applies to the `array` object. You can't prevent mutable access through the pointer, but you could add `const` member functions to give read-only access to them.

Answer (score 6):

> Maybe i should define a 'const' overloading operator or something in
>   order to make all of the elements in 'Arr' are immutable.

`A.Arr[i]` in your case is not immutable. `A.Arr` is.

You can not do the following:

```
A.Arr = newaddress;
++A.Arr; // etc
```

To overcome this problem, get rid of C style pointer (dynamic memory) and use:

```
int Arr[somesize];
```

or some container like `std::array` or `std::vector` to ensure your array is immutable.

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/PUJBk6) of compilation failing with `std::vector` as container.

Comment: @manuell No, I do mean `A.Arr` address is constant but not the contents pointed by it.

Comment: Ha ok. OP wants to modify n, though.

Comment: but still you could get the c pointer from the vector and change them manually without using the vector operators, it won't 100% disable you from changing the content.

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault. I mean in the line 'n = 10' is 'A.n = 10'

Comment: @Vladp In that case the behavior of program is undefined. What more can I say.

Comment: @Anderson just like that is impossible, since it's a generic pointer to memory you can change it's content at any moment, unless you change is to const int* for example, or the suggested vector

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the answers, since your class is named `Array`, you should have overloaded the array subscript operator accordingly:

```
int &operator[](int index) { return Arr[index]; } // non-const overload

int operator[](int index) const { return Arr[index]; } // const overload
```

With that, you'll no longer have to mess with that friend function.

Comment: in the const overload, doesn't the const only affect the function? the returned value still can be changed after that.

Comment: @Vladp it returns a copy - an rvalue, to which you cannot assign anything. Could be also `int const&`, but I go with a copy in case of a primitive type.

Comment: but when you call Array[3], how the compiler chooses which operator overload to use? does it depends on the Array at that scope whether its const or not?

Comment: @Vladp the non-const overload is preferred in case of non-const Array, the const overload is the only one matching in case of const Array.